# Display webpart property on webpart

Tags: web-part, custom-properties

I have a custom webpart property `optionalText` and it is showing in the tool box when we edit the webpart.

Now I want to show that property on webpart itself so that the user can see it without having to edit the webpart. Is there any way to do it?

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Gets or sets a value of Optional Text.
 /// </summary>
 [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
 public string OptionalText
 {
     get;
     set;
 }
```

Comment: You can assign the string value to a label. You won't be able to edit it without editing going to the WebPart Properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code

```
var page = "pageurl";
var limitedManager = SPContext.Current.Web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(page, PersonalizationScope.Shared);
//Replace WebPartClass with your webpart class name
var webPart = limitedManager.WebParts.OfType<WebPartClass>().FirstOrDefault();
var text = webPart.OptionalText;
```

Not each user can personalize the web part properties. So you need to read either user specific details or shared one.